# Check a checkbox in a table row where a "delete" icon has been clicked on using JQuery

Tags: jquery, checkbox

First, I'd want to tell that i'm not a native speaker so please forgive me my mistakes. Also, this is my first time posting here.

Here we go.
I've searched for days everywhere (especially here) the mistakes i could have made in my code. It's probably a very stupid mistake but i can't put my finger on it. I'm also new to Javascript and JQuery so this could be the reason.

I have a table with a checkbox and a delete icon in the first cell of each row of the table :

```
<tr>
<td colspan="2">
    <span>
        <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-select" value="13"/>
    </span> 
    <a href="">
        <img class="delete" src="/img/icons/delete.png" title="Delete" alt="Delete" align="right"/>
    </a>                                                                            
</td>
...
</tr>
```

What i need is to be able to check the checkbox when clicking on the icon (img).
What i've tried and doesn't work :

```
$('.delete').click(function(){
    var td = $(this).closest('td');
    var chkbox = td.children('.checkbox-select');
    chkbox.checked = true;   // or chkbox.prop('checked', true);
});
```

Please provide me the solution for my problem. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing right . You just need to to do `.find()` instead of `.children()`

```
$('.delete').click(function(){
 var td = $(this).closest('td');
 var chkbox = td.find('.checkbox-select');
 chkbox.prop('checked',true); 
});
```

`.children()` would search the immediate descendants. `.find()` will look into the enite inner nodes

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `.find()` instead of `.children()` because:

> The .children() method differs from .find() in that .children() only travels a single level down the DOM tree while .find() can traverse down multiple levels to select descendant elements (grandchildren, etc.) as well.

Also `chkbox` is jquery object of element. For using `.checked` property, you will need to convert jquery object to javascript DOM object:

```
chkbox[0].checked = true;
```

or use `.prop('checked', true)` with chkbox object:

```
chkbox.prop('checked', true)
```

Answer (score 0):

use **[find()](https://api.jquery.com/find/)** instead of **[children()](https://api.jquery.com/children/)**;

```
$('.delete').click(function(){
     $(this).closest('td').find('.checkbox-select').prop('checked', true);

   //or $(this).parent().prev().find('.checkbox-select').prop('checked', true);
});
```

NOTE: `$("td >.checkbox-select")` or `$("td").children(".checkbox-select")` it will select direct child only not all child ,use find in this case